# nginx - php5-fpm - woocommerce => settings dont save - only after restart of php5-fpm

Tags: nginx, debian, php-fpm

We are unable to save settings in woocommerce when php5-fpm is running for more then 12 hours.

Sometimes the changes are reflected in the DB but then don't show in the backend, other times the changes don't reach the DB at all.

When php5-fpm is restarted saving works right away.

This seems to be the same issue but no reply yet. > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528865/strange-wordpress-issue-not-saving-changes-solved-only-by-php5-fpm-restart

Thanks.

Comment: If you use (APC) opcode cache for PHP, disable / remove it and then try to reproduce the issue!

Comment: @Pothi I already disabled apc... (running apc.php gives: No cache info available. APC does not appear to be running.) But still we have saving issues. Any other ideas?

Comment: are you using some sort of load balancer? Who is your hosting company?

Comment: It seems that it does work right now. APC is still disabled so this probably fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Glad to know, everything is okay now!